# ImageMagick best fit text within rectangle?

Tags: text, dynamic, imagemagick, centering, best-fit

I have an image like this, with a rectangle at specific coordinates:

[image]

<sup>(for illustratory purposes I put the coordinates of the rectangle and its size and center in there)</sup>

Now I want to render some text with ImageMagick, so that it **fits exactly within the rectangle**.

If it's a very short (narrow) string, the rectangle's *height* will be the limiting factor:

[image: short string]

On the other hand with a long (wide) string, the rectangle's *width* will determine the size:

[image: long string]

In either case, independent of how short or long the text is, I would like to print it in one line (i.e. no word wrapping or multi line), and have it fit exactly in the rectangle, and make sure it's *centered* (the center of the text is in the center of the rectangle).

My questons:

1. How to do this 'best fit' feature with ImageMagick (I don't know how to dynamically determine the required `-pointsize` for this)
2. How to get the text centered, when I use `-gravity center` it seems to apply to the *position of the text within the entire image*, i.e. text coordinates become relative to the entire image's center. But I want to specify exact (absolute) coordinates, and that should be the center of the text.

For example, if I do this:

```
convert test.jpg -font Arial -fill yellow \
 -pointsize 65 -draw "text 398,90 'Hello'" test2.jpg
```

I'm getting:

[image: wrong]

Note how the coordinates I specify (the rectangle's center) become the *bottom left* anchor point for the text! (this surprised me)

And if I do:

```
convert test.jpg -font Arial -fill yellow \
 -pointsize 65 -gravity center -draw "text 148,-94 'Hello'" test3.jpg
```

I get:

[image: ok-ish]

Which is kinda OK, but note the weird text coordinates I have to use to get that. And besides I wouldn't know how to automatically calculate the pointsize (did the above by trial and error).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

With what I have now gathered, I think this may be your best option.

```
convert sea.jpg \( -size 173x50 -background none label:"A" -trim -gravity center -extent 173x50 \) -gravity northwest -geometry +312+66 -composite result.png
```

[image]

And this:

```
convert sea.jpg \( -size 173x50 -background none label:"A very much longer label" -trim -gravity center -extent 173x50 \) -gravity northwest -geometry +312+66 -composite result.png
```

[image]

Basically, I am using some *"aside processing"* in parentheses to generate the text and then compositing it onto the page afterwards. I generate the text with `label:` to the best automatic size, then trim off any excess space around the text. I then centre the trimmed text, using `-gravity center` and expand the background out (using `-extent`) so that the text box is always the same size, then I can position it (with `-geometry`) when compositing it relative to the top-left corner as I reset `-gravity` to `NorthWest`.

**Original Answer**

If you want ImageMagick to do its best to fit your text in a given box, you should use `caption` rather than `annotate`, `label` or `-draw "text"`.

So you want to load your sea image, set the size for the caption, draw the caption and composite that onto the image at the correct spot using `-geometry`:

```
convert sea.jpg -size 173x50! caption:"Your text" -geometry +312+66 -composite result.png
```

[image]

Or, with longer text:

```
convert sea.jpg -size 173x50! caption:"A considerably longer text that will result in a smaller font being chosen" -geometry +312+66 -composite result.png
```

[image]

---

If you want a blank background, use `-background none` before `caption:`

```
convert sea.jpg -size 173x50! -background none caption:"Your text" -geometry +312+66 -composite result.png
```

[image]

---

If you want to centre your text, you can do that with PANGO, like this, but I believe you then give up the auto-sizing feature:

```
convert sea.jpg -size 173x50! -background none -gravity center pango:'<span foreground="yellow">ABC</span>' -gravity northwest -geometry +312+66 -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the auto-sizing `caption` command. Still some questions though: the text is left-aligned (especially visible if I use a [very short string](http://i.imgur.com/vzw1zuN.png)), can I center it? Also, can I composite transparently so only the text itself is visible, and the background is unchanged? And can I avoid the wrap-around of text, i.e. force everything to be on a single line? Oh finally, just wondering, what is the ! in the size param for? (in `-size 173x50!`)

Comment: The exclamation mark means I specifically want exactly that size, I don't want **ImageMagick** to round things or manage proportions intelligently - it's a kind of a *"force"* option.

Comment: Actually, I got the transparent composite working by inserting `-background transparent -fill yellow` before the `-caption` command (edit -- aha, background none works as well, OK). But it seems the text doesn't fit the rectangle entirely, there is some unused space above and below?

Comment: I believe that, once you use `caption`, you hand over to ImageMagick the decision on line-breaks and can no longer control them. You *can* centre text, by using PANGO, then you give up the auto-sizing though. I'll put that in as an example also, but I am now thinking we will need a different approach... which I am working out. May take a bit longer.

Comment: Awesome, this works very well, and I learned some new handy things on ImageMagick as well. Thanks a lot, much appreciated!

Comment: Excellent - glad to be of assistance! Btw, I would put the `173x50` in a shell variable because I hate to see numbers repeated in commands - makes a maintenance nightmare. Good luck with your project and remember, questions (and answers) are free, so come back and ask another if you get stuck again :-)