# PHP Imagick function to add a label

Tags: php, imagemagick

I found an imagemagick convert command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764846/imagemagick-best-fit-text-within-rectangle) to fit text into a smaller box, namely

```
convert sea.jpg \( -size 173x50 -background none label:"A" -trim -gravity center -extent 173x50 \) -gravity northwest -geometry +312+66 -composite result.png
```

I'm trying to replicate this in PHP using [the IMagick library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php)
However, I can't seem to find a way to add a label? The [IMagick LabelImage function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.labelimage.php) doesn't actually add a label on the image but only the metadata.

my current attempt got me so far:

```
    $label = new Imagick();
    $label->newImage(173,50,new ImagickPixel('transparent'),"png");
    $label->labelImage("Testing 123");
    $label->trimImage(0);
    $label->setGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
```

However the labelImage, as said, doesn't actually add anything to the image, so I think I've hit a dead end.
What would be a good way to add a label to an image, or in general are there better ways to add text to an image in a shrink-to-fit way in a box using the IMagick library?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used **IMagick** for ages, and will delete this if incorrect, but I guess you probably want [newPseudoImage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.newpseudoimage.php) with `label:` as the type. Sorry I can't test this, but something like:

```
label = Imagick::newPseudoImage ( 173, 50, "label:The text you want")
Composite over your background
```

Comment: I tried it, with some code from example 1 of [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.newpseudoimage.php),and made a file that does nothing more than create an image, add a pseudoimage and return it. however that doesn't seem to work with label? It works with the pseudo string "plasma:fractal" which gives a pretty image, but "label:Test" doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you could add your latest/greatest code into your question? Click the `edit` button under it to get started.